# How does enum.toString() work under the hood?

Tags: c#, enums, tostring

I am an iOS developer and I regret that in Objective-C there is no the amazing method toString for enum like in C#

So I am very curious to know how the toString method works for enum in C#.

Maybe with your answers I will understand why Objective-C has not this method implemented.

Thanks

Comment: Use something like Telerik JustDecompile and have a look yourself.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs#36729210e317a805

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C# compiler actually turns enumerations into regular `class` types, and makes them behave like an enumeration by a combination of [syntax sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) and some help from methods in the .NET framework (particularly the [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.type) and [`Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes).

What actually happens when you declare an `enum` type is that the compiler creates a hidden, specially-named class which conceptually looks like this:

```
public sealed class EnumName : Enum
{
    public static readonly int FirstValue = 0;
    public static readonly int SecondValue = 1;
    // etc.
}
```

The `Enum` base class is a special base class that you cannot use directly. It provides the `ToString()` method. This sets off a series of function calls internal to the .NET framework. The code ends up in [`Type.GetEnumName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getenumname.aspx) and finally a private `Type.GetEnumData()` method which uses reflection to examine the `EnumName` class, look at its fields (enumeration values) and get and return their names.

The call graph (in chronological order) looks like this:

```
Enum.ToString()
  Enum.InternalFormat(RuntimeType, object)
    Enum.GetName(RuntimeType, object)
      Type.GetEnumName(object)
        Type.GetEnumRawConstantValues()
          Type.GetEnumData(out string[], out Array)
        Type.GetEnumNames()
          Type.GetEnumData(out string[], out Array)
```

`GetEnumData()` calls [`Type.GetFields()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and iterates over them, copying the name and integral value (enum value) of each field into the output array.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is clear and I understood very well how enum toString method works.

Answer (score 2):

Internally `ToString` will call a method called `Enum.InternalFormat`, which in turn just calls `Enum.GetName`, here's the decompiled code (.NET v4.0)

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public override string ToString()
{
  return Enum.InternalFormat((RuntimeType) this.GetType(), this.GetValue());
}

private static string InternalFormat(RuntimeType eT, object value)
{
  if (!eT.IsDefined(typeof (FlagsAttribute), false))
    return Enum.GetName((Type) eT, value) ?? value.ToString();
  else
    return Enum.InternalFlagsFormat(eT, value);
}
```

For enums marked with the `Flags` attribute, it calls another method called `InternalFlagsFormat` which builds up a CSV of all the enum names

```
private static string InternalFlagsFormat(RuntimeType eT, object value)
{
  ulong num1 = Enum.ToUInt64(value);
  ulong[] values;
  string[] names;
  Enum.GetCachedValuesAndNames(eT, out values, out names, true, true);
  int index = values.Length - 1;
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  bool flag = true;
  ulong num2 = num1;
  for (; index >= 0 && (index != 0 || (long) values[index] != 0L); --index)
  {
    if (((long) num1 & (long) values[index]) == (long) values[index])
    {
      num1 -= values[index];
      if (!flag)
        stringBuilder.Insert(0, ", ");
      stringBuilder.Insert(0, names[index]);
      flag = false;
    }
  }
  if ((long) num1 != 0L)
    return value.ToString();
  if ((long) num2 != 0L)
    return ((object) stringBuilder).ToString();
  if (values.Length > 0 && (long) values[0] == 0L)
    return names[0];
  else
    return "0";
}
```

For the latest implementation, see the [Microsoft source reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs#1365cfeffd45409d).

Comment: The microsoft provided source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs#1365cfeffd45409d

Answer (score 0):

ToString simply returns the string equivelent of the Name of the specific enum value (note, this can differ from it's value).

```
public enum SomeEnum {
    Text1 = 1,
    Text2 = 2,
    Text3 = 3,
}

var some = SomeEnum.Text1
```

`some.ToString()` returns `"Text1"`

In the case of a flagged enum (using FlagsAttribute on the declaration) it would return a string equivelent of all selected enum values

```
var some = SomeEnum.Text1 & SomeEnum.Text2
```

`"Text1 | Text2"`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was not about what `ToString` does, but how does it do it.

Comment: I believe that it is using reflection to accomplish this (thats how I would have done it anyways).

Comment: So it is the C# compiler which keep a string for each key of an enum ?

Comment: If we have an instance of an enumerated type we can map that value to one of several string representations by calling the ToString method inherited from System.Enum

Answer (score 0):

If we have an instance of an enumerated type we can map that value to one of several string representations by calling the ToString method inherited from System.Enum

Below is the sample code

```
class Program
{
    enum Days
    {
        Sun,
        Mon,
        Tue,
        Wed,
        Thu,
        Fri,
        Sat
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Days obj = Days.Mon;

        Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString("G"));  // output - Mon (Normal)
        Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString("D"));  // output - 1 (Decimal)
        Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString("X"));  // output - 00000001 (Hexadecimal)    
    }
}
```